# ImageView adds white space around my image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView that when I look at in the XML preview layout on Eclipse looks fine, but when I launch the app on my hardware device a big [whitespace](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22623301/Screenshot_2012-08-23-21-16-51.png) comes to surround it. This is what the actual [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0KWv.jpg) is, without the whitespace that is being added. Here is my [XML file](http://pastebin.com/v0JBJXeD)  too. How do I get rid of this whitespace?

Comment: Will that image ever be larger than the screen itself? As in, is the image dynamic, with different sizes (one of which may need to shrink down)?

Comment: Well the image was 566x177 so not sure if thats bigger than my Galaxy s3 screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image shouldn't be too large, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/linkMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="cat"
        android:src="@drawable/ashsc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This way, the image won't attempt to scale and won't create bounds outside the `ImageView`'s image.